# li span float left float right

Tags: html, css

I need to do the following:

```
|text1| lots of text lots of text lots |text3|
lots of text lots of text lots of text lots 
of text
```

It is structured as:

```
<li><span>text1</span><span>text3</span><span>lots of text</span></li>
```

text3 is float right.

The problem is that I need to set a width on lots of text as I need the background colour to fill the entire width of the row. If I set it to float:left, it goes down a line and is not on the same line as text1 or text2.

Comment: its not very obvious what you are tring to do. maybe an image of the final look will help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RBfX4/)

```css
span {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

span.withbg {
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span id="left">text1</span>
    <span class="withbg">lots of text</span>
    <span id="right">text3</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: how about an 1 up there..? :-)